# How to setup collapsing toolbar in bottom sheet?

Tags: java, android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to set up a collapsing toolbar in my bottomsheet xml, but it seems that the collapsing toolbar won't collapse when the bottomsheet is expanded. Any way to make it collapse when bootomsheet is expanded? Here is my code:

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/expandedImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/photo"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Show what you tried inside your activity.